# VBA Global/Public variable scope

Tags: vba, variables, global

I need advice on how to retain a variable value assigned in "Private Sub" and pass it onto "Main Sub"

code would look like this:

````
Global DocDate as String
Sub Main()

```(some code before)```
Call RemitterParsing

```this goes for 8 different values```
Set objDocDate = objDoc.createElement("PayerDocumentDa")
objRemitt.appendChild objDocDate
objDocDate.Text = DocDate


End Sub

Private Sub RemitterParsing()
    OpenPosition = InStr(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, "PayerDocumentDa>")
    closeposition = InStr(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, "</PayerDocumentDa")
    DocDate = Mid(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, OpenPosition + 16, closeposition - OpenPosition - 16)

End Sub
````

Thats why i want to call another sub to get all 8 values at once ant then use them in the main sub. Function would call them 8 times.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. and read [ask] then edit question (e.g. search web for question title and add code that is relevant, as your sample won't fail on scope as long as code is in same module).

Comment: What is your message? I would expect your code to work. Without more detail, it is very hard to help, but do you really need to use a global variable? Can you not turn assignValue into a Function returning String?

Comment: The thing is my original code needs to return 8 different values and for some reason this approach returns blank.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as is.

But I'd advise against using `Public` variables unless necessary, and pass variables between subs, as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim var1 As String ' declare a variable in scope with Main sub

    assignValue var1 ' call 'assignValue' sub passing it the variable to be set
    MsgBox var1 ' see variable has been set

End Sub

Private Sub assignValue(var1 As String) ' have the sub accept a variable as argument
    var1 = "Hello" ' set the passed variable
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe a function is easier to understand than a (implicit!) ByRef for newbies. And a procedure that assigns sth. is indicates a Property Let/Set for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, my approach worked, but I found an error. I have declared that value within main sub again as "Dim". Deleted it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If I read that comment right("The thing is my original code needs to return 8 different values..."), you might want to try something like this, utilizing a [User Definded Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement) (UDT, commonly known as `Structure` in other languages):

````
' Define the UDT in the General section of a module
Type MyReturnValues
' Expand the individual UDT members as needed
   Value1 As String
   Value2 As Long
   Value3 As Date
   ' ... More members, if needed
   DocDate As String
End Type

Sub Main()

   Dim udtReturn As MyReturnValues

   ' ```(some code before)```
   udtReturn = RemitterParsing()

   ' Show the results of RemitterParsing()
   With udtReturn
      Debug.Print "Value1: "; .Value1, "Value2: "; .Value2, "Value3: "; .Value3, "DocDate: "; .DocDate
   End With

   ' ```this goes for 8 different values```
   Set objDocDate = objDoc.createElement("PayerDocumentDa")
   objRemitt.appendChild objDocDate
   objDocDate.Text = DocDate

End Sub

Private Function RemitterParsing() As MyReturnValues

   Dim udt As MyReturnValues

   OpenPosition = InStr(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, "PayerDocumentDa>")
   closeposition = InStr(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, "</PayerDocumentDa")
   udt.DocDate = Mid(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, OpenPosition + 16, closeposition - OpenPosition - 16)

   ' Populate a 2nd UDT member
   OpenPosition2 = InStr(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, "PayerDocumentDa>")
   closeposition2 = InStr(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, "</PayerDocumentDa")
   udt.Value1 = Mid(Range(foundRmt.Address).Offset(2, 0).Value, OpenPosition + 16, closeposition - OpenPosition - 16)

   ' Add random stuff for demonstration
   With udt
      .Value2 = 123
      .Value3 = Now()
   End With

   ' Return the values
   RemitterParsing = udt

End Function
````